# R: Assigning group value based on subset of that group

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, tidyverse

Is there a way to assign a mean taken from a specific group level to the entire group? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do - I'm using library(tidyverse).

Given:

```
> DF <- data.frame(A = c("P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2"), B = c("Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No"), C = c(10,10,2,20,3,3))
> DF
   A   B  C
1 P1 Yes 10
2 P1 Yes 10
3 P1  No  2
4 P2 Yes 20
5 P2  No  3
6 P2  No  3
```

I would like to create "mean" based on the average of B="Yes" grouped by "A":

```
> DF <- data.frame(A = c("P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2"), B = c("Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No"), C = c(10,10,2,20,3,3))
> DF
   A   B  C  mean
1 P1 Yes 10  10
2 P1 Yes 10  10
3 P1  No  2  10
4 P2 Yes 20  20
5 P2  No  3  20
6 P2  No  3  20
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
> DF %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(temp = ifelse(B=="Yes", 1, 0), s= sum(temp), mean = sum(C*temp)/s)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
       A      B     C  temp     s  mean
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     P1    Yes    10     1     2    10
2     P1    Yes    10     1     2    10
3     P1     No     2     0     2    10
4     P2    Yes    20     1     1    20
5     P2     No     3     0     1    20
6     P2     No     3     0     1    20
```

Comment: You could simplify it this way : `DF %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(mean=mean(C[B=="Yes"]))`

Comment: In `data.table`, you could use `library(data.table); setDT(DF)` to convert DF to a data.table and then use `DF[, .(B=B, C=C, mean=mean(C[B=="Yes"])), by=A]` to return your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward method in base R is to calculate the desired means by group and then merge these results on the original data.frame.

```
merge(DF, aggregate(cbind(mean=C)~A, data=DF[DF$B=="Yes",], mean), by="A")
   A   B  C mean
1 P1 Yes 10   10
2 P1 Yes 10   10
3 P1  No  2   10
4 P2 Yes 20   20
5 P2  No  3   20
6 P2  No  3   20
```

The "trick" here is that that data.frame fed to `aggregate` only contains the "Yes" observations.

---

An more robust version of my `data.table` answer in the comments is to replace `.(...)` with `c(.SD, mean=...)` like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, c(.SD, mean=mean(C[B=="Yes"])), by=A]
    A   B  C mean
1: P1 Yes 10   10
2: P1 Yes 10   10
3: P1  No  2   10
4: P2 Yes 20   20
5: P2  No  3   20
6: P2  No  3   20
```

This replacement will allow any additional variables to be passed through.